# what are some reliable international proxy server providers that I can use to test webpages as viewed in other countries

Tags: proxy

My group runs several websites with international audiences and we use geo-targeting to serve personalized experiences based on their IP region.

We use the Foxy Proxy plugin for Firefox so we can test whether the correct content is being served.  A lot of the free proxy servers are unreliable, and I am looking for recommendations on setting these up reliably ourselves somehow, or companies that do this.

Answer (score 2):

Gomez Networks (www.gomeznetworks.com) provides services like what you seem to be looking for. They can generate synthetic transactions from various global locations and parse the HTML return to determine if it's compliant to your requirements.

We've used it for about a year to analyze site performance for overseas customers and it works pretty well. Not a magic bullet but better than nothing.